# Asp.net Web API model binding NULL on POST request

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, vue.js, asp.net-core

when I make a POST request from my frontend (vue.js) to asp.net web API (using .net CORE), model binding shows null when using a complex type in the method of the controller, when I send a json object request directly, But when I convert the json to a json string in the frontend and send it with one variable the request works.

My request from vue.js.

```
let data = JSON.stringify({"name":"myname","phone":"555555"});

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:4003/api/Controller/Request',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};
```

As you can see above I need to convert it into a string and then send the json string in one variable.  (this works)

But if I send the request as just a direct raw json body the complex model shows all `null` values

```
axios.post(http://localhost:4003/api/Controller/Request, {
        "name": "myname",
        "phone": "5555555"
       }, {
        headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                 }
      });
```

my method for my controller is as

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] NameModel input)
```

and the DTO NameModel is

```
public class NameModel
    {
        public string name { get;set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
   }
```

*Now my questions are, why is model binding not mapping the property names directly in the raw request? since reading through the docs this is suppose to happen automatically when using a complex type*

also how is the mapping happening when I only send one variable `data` from the frontend is something happening in the `startup.cs` file of services of `Iconfigure`?

Comment: You might want to use `{name: "myname",phone: "5555555"}`

Comment: Hi, yeah I have tried that as well.

Comment: There are no _quotes_ around the URL in `axios.post(http://localhost:4003/api/Controller/Request`.

Comment: @PHPNoob you need to stringify the data in the second example.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine on my side. Maybe you can debug it with f12 to see if there is any error,  also check the request payload.

Comment: @Nkosi yeah, my question is relating to why do I need to stringify the json when I am using a complex type in my method, so according to the docs I shouldn't have to do this since it should auto bind with a raw json request, as I am using the same property names as well.

Comment: if the format of the data passed does not match the expected encoding then it wont bind. That is just how it was designed.

Comment: @Nkosi yeah, I had a `float` type in the json model from the frontend, yet the backend was declared as a `string` type so this was causing this issue causing the model to not bind. Since there was a mismatch of types.